# Set and retreive routerLink parameters via json in Angular2

Tags: json, angular, router

I've got a list of items generated by `*ngFor` in Angular2. 
I want each of the items to work as a link to the full page with description of that item.

The generated data is retrieved via `json`.

As I want to use the items as links, I guess they should have router parameters like that `[routerLink]="['/items', item.description]"` in order to redirect users to the description page.

The question is how to pass such parameters via `json` (I can't bind them directly to the link in my `html`) ?

My item structure (div **itemBlock** supposed to work as a link):

```
<div class="itemBlock" *ngFor="let item of items">
    <img src="{{item.image}}" alt="Item image" class="item--image">
    <h3 class="item--name">{{item.name}}</h3>
    <span class="item--number">{{item.number}}</span>
</div>
```

Json structure:

```
[
    {
      "id":"Item 1",
      "name": "Item 1 Name",
      "image": "./item1.jpg",
      "number": "Number 1"
    },
    {
      "id":"Item 2",
      "name": "Item 2 Name",
      "image": "./item2.jpg",
      "number": "Number 2"
    },
    ...,
    ...
    ]
```

Comment: No. You would typically use `[routerLink]="['/items', item.id]"`, and use that id to get the details of the item from the detail component.

Comment: Ok, thanx! I'll do this way.